# Creating a ranged, paralyzing weapon

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, weapons

I have a story. I have the good guys. I want to keep the good guys as good guys. I have some anti-heroes who I don't want to have to be killed by the good guys. I want them to be captured with the non-lethal paralyzer mode just like what happened to Kagari from Psycho-Pass.

Now I would normally say [PEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsed_energy_projectile)(si) but then I realized something:

> *"Wait a min, who do I actually want to subdue?"*

- A Lightning draconian who regularly employs lightning to fry his enemies?!
- Genetically engineered super soldiers?!

**NOO!**

PEP paralyzes the target by using **E**lectro **M**agnetic **P**ulses to temporarily wreck the nervous system of the target. The problem is that most creatures who got subdued are either had thick skin/scales/fur or iron armor, or just a biology that enables them to survive constant electrocution 24/7, so PEP is not a viable option. What other options do I have?

So we're looking for weapon(s) that can:

- Disable really tough creatures to a point where handcuffing them isn't a complete suicide mission.
- Has minimal chances of being accidentally deadly (if the target gets permanently injured, that's not a problem, *we have a team's pet axolotl, and a gene lab*)
- Be fired from a distance.

---

Please edit the answers according to the changes.

Comment: Your big images don't fit with the site's culture or editorial style.

Comment: @JDługosz Better? The Too damn high picture will be kept for informational and recreational purposes.

Comment: Better?  Well, maybe you’ll get half as many downvotes and mod flags with only one such “recreational” image.

Comment: @JDługosz seriously, it's a link picture, to get everyone on the same page.

Comment: I posted to [meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4792/what-pictures-do-we-like-and-dislike-in-a-post).

Comment: You should stop posting images to your questions until you are better able to judge what images might go with what questions. Also, provide all needed information in the post, not in links. Links are how you get viruses, especially links from weird meme-ish pictures. Also also, you need to explain how the weapon you imagine isn't a taser. I don't know what you are asking, so I am voting to close.

Comment: the problem is, it is no obvious what the information value of the image itself is. It may be some deeply valuable reference, but at first glance, it is just a stupid picture with no information.(yes I saw it should be a link, but I do not see why should I click it)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You got two options I think. Sound and current. So you either shock them like a taser. Could be taser shotgun shells for example. Or even [laser guns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsed_energy_projectile) set to stun. Like the PEP project.

Sound would be a [vomit ray](http://io9.gizmodo.com/358228/testing-the-sonic-blaster-vomit-gun). Which according to Google also works with [light](https://www.wired.com/2007/08/flashlight-vomi/). Besides nausea it can also be used to mess with the targets inner ear, causing in a way paralyzes. As the target can't find enough balance to even crawl. All they can do is lay down.

Comment: Can I deliver a huge enough current, that knocks out the person (lightning can do it) but doesn't cause physical harm?

Comment: No, any stun gun that's strong enough to knock a person out has the chance of causing damage to the hearth. None of them are 100% non-lethal and 100% effective.

Comment: Can I lower the chances of damage by using super good conductors, like graphene, or causing shellshock?

Comment: It's related to how the human body reacts to a shock. Any non-lethal has some chance to kill your target. Even the vomit ray could let the target choke on his vomit. Target might have a weak heart and just die of shock and stress etc.

Comment: Dominators are able to scan people's minds, determining physical defects shouldn't be a problem for them.

Comment: @RedactedRedacted You assume people are aware of their condition. That's naive.

Comment: Sure do that, still can choke on vomit, when being crippled they can take a nasty fall. Rubber bullets can hit an eye, tasers can wreck the heart, lasers to the eyes can blind. There Always risks.

Comment: Essentially there is no such thing as a non-lethal weapon only less-lethal ones. Stun-guns or paralyzing pistols are a pleasant fantasy fit only for comic books and old-time science-fiction. Anything that can disable a person can potentially kill them.

Comment: @RedactedRedacted "Can I deliver a huge enough current, that knocks out the person (lightning can do it) but doesn't cause physical harm?" - shoot something magnetic so it fly nearby the target with good velocity, it will have EM shockwave on its trajectory. Or just shoot EM grenade, so that it detonates nearby. Plasma bubble. Plasma trace - to conduct electricity to the target. Ionization of stuff near the target and EM fast moving projectile or EM grenade. etc.